# VertexAI: RunName of Experiment

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is it possible to get a list of runs for a given experiment using google.cloud.aiplatform?

I've looked through the docs and can't see an obvious way to retrieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `google.cloud.aiplatform` library doesn't directly provide a method to list runs of your experiments.

I can only think of two ways to achieve this, either through the [Google Cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/experiments/log-data#view-runs-list) or via [Vertex AI SDK for Python](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/experiments/log-data#view-runs-list:%7E:text=for%20this%20purpose.-,Vertex%20AI%20SDK%20for%20Python,-View%20on%20GitHub).

```
def log_metrics_sample(
    experiment_name: str,
    run_name: str,
    metrics: Dict[str, float],
    project: str,
    location: str,
):
    aiplatform.init(experiment=experiment_name, project=project, location=location)

    aiplatform.start_run(run=run_name)

    aiplatform.log_metrics(metrics)
```